# fread does not see eof c++

Tags: c++, file-io, binaryfiles

I've written a binary file with he following function :

```
int writeFile(FILE *f_to, void *from, int size){
    int write = fwrite(from, 1, size, f_to);
    if (write == size)
        return 0;
    else
        return -1; //fails
}

void createDataFile(const char *fname)
{
    FILE * out_file;
    out_file = fopen(fname, "ab+");
    if (out_file == NULL){
        std::cout << "error no file to be written" << endl;
    }



        writeFile(out_file, (INT32U*)&(newPtr->hdr), sizeof(S_MES_HDR));
        writeFile(out_file, (INT32U*)&(newPtr->mon_hdr), sizeof(S_MON_HEADER));
        writeFile(out_file, (INT32U*)&(newPtr->data_hdr), sizeof(S_MON_DATA_HEADER));
        writeFile(out_file, (INT32U*)&(newPtr->data), ((ptr->hdr.id.data_len*sizeof(INT32U)) - sizeof(S_MON_HEADER)-sizeof(S_MON_DATA_HEADER)));

        cout<<  sizeof(S_MES_HDR)<<endl;
        cout<< sizeof(S_MON_HEADER)<<endl;
        cout<< sizeof(S_MON_DATA_HEADER)<<endl;
        cout<<((ptr->hdr.id.data_len*sizeof(INT32U)) - sizeof(S_MON_HEADER)-sizeof(S_MON_DATA_HEADER))<<endl;

        fclose(out_file);
        S_TERM_PACKET *monPacketPointer2;
        monPacketPointer2 = new S_TERM_PACKET;
        out_file = fopen(fname, "ab+");
        createMessage(monPacketPointer2, 1, 'R', 6, out_file);
        fclose(out_file);
        S_TERM_PACKET *monPacketPointer3;
        monPacketPointer3 = new S_TERM_PACKET;
        out_file = fopen(fname, "ab+");
        createMessage(monPacketPointer3, 3, 'M', 3, out_file);
        fclose(out_file);

    cout << "output file has been created." << endl;
}



   int main()
    {
       createDataFile("test.data");
       return 0;
    }
```

and I got the following output: http://prntscr.com/43dpsm . Total number of  bytes that I've written into test.data file is *(16+8+4+40)*3=204 bytes.*

Now, when I read test.data file with the following function:

```
      int ReadFile(FILE *f_in, void *dest, int size)
     {
         int read = fread(dest, 1, size, f_in);
         if (read == size){
             return 0;
         }
         return -1;
     }


     void readData(const char* id, Structure*head)
        {
 ReadFile(p_file, (INT32U*)&termPacketPointer->hdr, sizeof(S_MES_HDR));

                    cout << "total read size:" << sizeof(S_MES_HDR)+(termPacketPointer->           hdr.id.data_len)*sizeof(INT32U) << endl;
        cout << "data len:" << (termPacketPointer->hdr.id.data_len) << endl;
                 ReadFile(p_file, (INT32U*)&termPacketPointer->term_data, (termPacketPointer-> hdr.id.data_len)*sizeof(INT32U));
         }

     int main()
      {
           // createDataFile("test.data");
              File * p_file=fopen("test.data", "rb");
              if(p_file==NULL)
                   return -1;

              if (!feof(p_file))
              {
                readData("25", head);
              }
              if (!feof(p_file))
              {
                readData("25", head);
              }
              if (!feof(p_file))
              {
                readData("25", head);
              }
              if (!feof(p_file))
              {
                readData("25", head);
              }

                fclose(p_file);
                return 0;
       }
```

I got the following output and run-time error at the end.

total read size: 68
data len:13

total read size: 68
data len:13

total read size: 68
data len:13

total read size: 210756
data len:52685

So, after reading 68*3 =204 bytes ,which is equal to number of bytes that I've written into file, it did not stop and continued to read. My assumption is that it did not see *eof* but I know fclose put it automatically. How could I solve my problem ? thanks in advance.

Comment: You got that PNG image as output? That *is* unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing which would help a lot is to actually check the return status of `fread()`.  The inner function does that and returns -1 for error, but the call in `main()` to that does not check the status.

In many implementations, `feof()` does not become true until an attempt to read past the end of file.